How accurate is a battery test?
My daughter's car recently failed to start, empty battery. Daddy's jump leads helped. But just a few days earlier she had driven several hundred kilometers so the battery should have been fully charged. I advised her to get the battery checked, which she did, and they said it was OK. This was at a reputable battery shop, if they had failed it she would almost certainly have bought a new battery from them, so they had no incentive to cheat.
I was most surprised at this and will try to look for unexpected current drain (not easy when the fuseboxes are hidden all over the car). I guess their battery test involved measuring the voltage off- and on-load. Are there failure modes which would allow passing the test but still give an empty battery so quickly?
Edit: (in response to @MTA's post) it seems that they did a digital test (she didn't witness it, it took 10 minutes, and they offered to charge the battery).

Presuming the drive belt is tight, have the alternator tested. A battery is only as good as its connections being free of corrosion, tight drive belt and working alternator.

Based on the fact that the battery was not fully charged when tested, it is less than certain that the battery test was valid. Testing the alternator as @FDryer recommends is a good and logical next step, and if that reveals no alternator problem and the drive belt is tight and all connections are clean and tight, then a full battery charge and a high current load test on the battery is next. If the battery is good, consider testing for current drain. Many posts here about current drain.

Make sure the connection to the battery are clean.   Check grounds. With the engine running, check the voltage at the battery.  It should be around 13.5-14.5.  If it's lower, there may be an issue with the alternator.  You can do a parasitic load test with a multimeter than can read DC amps.  Disconnect the negative terminal of the battery.  Put the ammeter in 10A mode.  Connect it between the negative terminal and negative wire.  Once you verify the draw is low enough, you can move it to the mA mode.  The draw should be less than 50mA once the computers finish their initial startup.

Accuracy depends on the testing method, testing equipment and testing technician.
When we test a battery, we want to answer the question: Will this battery provide the volts and amps required to turn a starter fast enough and for enough time to start the engine under the worst expected temperature conditions?
There are two main testing methods: digital (computer-based) testing and high amp testing.
Digital testing involves a tester that looks like a multimeter with small battery clamps and thin wires, perhaps as thick as a typical USB cable. The technician enters any required battery specifications into the device. When the test begins, the device measures voltage very accurately and places a small load on the battery, and measures voltage change with the load. Then the internal computer consults its algorithm, refers to its map of all possible voltage curves, and reports good, weak or bad. It may also report the cold cranking amps (CCA) that the battery should be able to produce.
This method is not perfect. It is not an actual real-world test of performance, but a projection or prediction based on a computer model that usually works, but not always. There are edge cases that clearly fall outside the capabilities of a computer model to predict performance. We have had such cases on this Stack where digital testing produced false "good battery" results when the battery was clearly bad.
The other testing method, the high amp method, is 100% reliable because it is not a simulation or projection, but an actual, severe test using the same or more amps that are required to start a car under difficult circumstances.
A high amp tester sometimes comes on wheels, or it can be portable with a handle like a small briefcase. It has large battery clamps with high-force springs that might take 2 hands to open. The battery cables are thick like jumper cables. For the test to be valid, the battery must be fully charged, and this may be the reason that high amp testing is less common today: if the customer has to wait 1-2 hours to get results while the battery fully charges, it's not great for business.
The test is performed by adjusting a knob or crank until the tester is drawing 50% of the battery's CCA. So for example, if it is an 800 CCA battery, the tester is drawing 400 amps. This high load is maintained for 15 seconds, and then the voltage is measured at the end of this 15 seconds just before the load is disconnected. That voltage is compared to a table of voltages at various temperatures, and the results are reported as good, weak or bad. (Some models of tester may use slightly different amps or time standards, but the principle is the same.)
So you see that this test shows actual performance of the battery as if it is cranking a cold engine for a long time. A clearly bad battery will have its voltage fall below 10 volts as soon as the heavy load is started. An old battery nearing the end of its useful life will have its voltage drop slowly toward 10 or 10.5 volts as the 15 second load progresses. A new, good battery will maintain a steady high voltage for the duration of the test.
If you want to be 100% certain that you have a good battery, start with a fully charged battery and insist on a high amp test.

Thanks for the info, I have asked my daughter if she saw what sort of test they used. I shall add the info to my question when she replies.
